# I am trying to generate a title page but compiler shows error in title page

Tags: pdftex, titles

The code for my title page is

```
\title{
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
    \huge  Artificial Neural Networks\\
        \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=100px,width=100px]{index.jpg}\\[15pt]
\end{center}

    \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
    \huge Project Report\\[10pt]
    \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{Department of Mathematics\\ MTU} \\ [25pt]
 }

\author{
    \normalfont                                 
    XYZ, \\[5pt]
    ABC\\[5pt]
    UVW\\[2pt]      \normalsize
    \today
}
 \date{}

\maketitle
```

I am getting the following error

"Paragraph ended before \title was complete."

I don't understand why this error is coming. I am using pdfLatex for compiling.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please consider providing a complete, small document people can compile to reproduce the problem. This makes it much easier to help effectively and to understand your question. I think you need to use a `titlepage` environment if you want to do this. `\title` is just meant for the, well, title. The `titling` package may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?  You leave blank lines in the `\title{...}` which causes the errors and you did not provide the `\horrule{}`, so this solution adds one.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\ [0.4cm]
    \huge  Artificial Neural Networks\\
    \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=100px,width=100px]{example-image-a}\\[15pt]
\end{center}
    \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
    \huge Project Report\\[10pt]
    \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{Department of Mathematics\\ MTU} \\ [25pt]
 }
\author{
    \normalfont                                 
    XYZ, \\[5pt]
    ABC  \\[5pt]
    UVW\\[2pt]     
    \normalsize
    \today
}
 \date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```